# Created query is not supported by my DB

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, informix

I created an application using seam-gen. The created operation to search the DB ends with and exception (syntax error). The query has a where clause like this:

```
lower(barcode0_.barcode_ean) like lower((?||'%')) limit ?
```

Does hibnerate or seam create the where clause which my DB can't understand?

Or is there a workaround for SQL statement related issues in seam?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which database you are using, and exactly what query is being run.

Comment: @Shervin Informix is the DB. Postgres works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert of Seam  but this looks like the problem mentioned in [this thread](http://seamframework.org/Community/SeamgenSearchProblemWithLowerInDB2WithFix) (see also [JBSEAM-3297](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-3297)). The suggested solution is use `lower(concat` instead of `concat(lower` in `seam-gen/src/EntityList.java.ftl`.